# Windows - refresh PATH

Tags: windows, command-line, path

I have changed the PATH variable in Windows 7.
However, when I open a command line window, and run
`echo %path%` it still displays the old PATH.

How can I refresh PATH in the command line?
I can not restart or log out.

Answer (score 0):

Changing any variable in one batch session wil not affect any other batch session.

You would need to use the `setx` command (see `setx /?` from the prompt) to make any change visible in any sessions that start after your `setx` was executed.

```
set "path=%path%;abcd"
```

will append `abcd` to the path variable (the `PATH` variable is a set of directorynames separated by semicolons.)

```
setx path "%path%"
```

will assign the current value of path (%path%) as the value of path for all future instances for this user. `%path%` is wuoted as it may contain spaces.

```
setx path "%path%" /m
```

will assign the current value of path (%path%) as the value of path for all future instances for all users of this **machine**.

Comment: I can't understand well from the instructions. If I want to set the PATH variable to `abcd` do I do `SETX MYPATH ~abcd~` ?

Comment: WARNING!!! Don't use `setx` because it will truncate your variables loosing some of them. Use GUI instead System Properties -> Environment Variables.

Answer (score 0):

Took this from the chocolatey repo, save it to anything you want .cmd and run it, it should refresh the paths right every single time without reboot, for some reason the other methods involving commands like `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\CmdShortcuts` did not work for me in the newest versions of win 10 and 11.

````
::
:: RefreshEnv.cmd
::
:: Batch file to read environment variables from registry and
:: set session variables to these values.
::
:: With this batch file, there should be no need to reload command
:: environment every time you want environment changes to propagate

::echo "RefreshEnv.cmd only works from cmd.exe, please install the Chocolatey Profile to take advantage of refreshenv from PowerShell"
echo | set /p dummy="Refreshing environment variables from registry for cmd.exe. Please wait..."

goto main

:: Set one environment variable from registry key
:SetFromReg
    "%WinDir%\System32\Reg" QUERY "%~1" /v "%~2" > "%TEMP%\_envset.tmp" 2>NUL
    for /f "usebackq skip=2 tokens=2,*" %%A IN ("%TEMP%\_envset.tmp") do (
        echo/set "%~3=%%B"
    )
    goto :EOF

:: Get a list of environment variables from registry
:GetRegEnv
    "%WinDir%\System32\Reg" QUERY "%~1" > "%TEMP%\_envget.tmp"
    for /f "usebackq skip=2" %%A IN ("%TEMP%\_envget.tmp") do (
        if /I not "%%~A"=="Path" (
            call :SetFromReg "%~1" "%%~A" "%%~A"
        )
    )
    goto :EOF

:main
    echo/@echo off >"%TEMP%\_env.cmd"

    :: Slowly generating final file
    call :GetRegEnv "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" >> "%TEMP%\_env.cmd"
    call :GetRegEnv "HKCU\Environment">>"%TEMP%\_env.cmd" >> "%TEMP%\_env.cmd"

    :: Special handling for PATH - mix both User and System
    call :SetFromReg "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" Path Path_HKLM >> "%TEMP%\_env.cmd"
    call :SetFromReg "HKCU\Environment" Path Path_HKCU >> "%TEMP%\_env.cmd"

    :: Caution: do not insert space-chars before >> redirection sign
    echo/set "Path=%%Path_HKLM%%;%%Path_HKCU%%" >> "%TEMP%\_env.cmd"

    :: Cleanup
    del /f /q "%TEMP%\_envset.tmp" 2>nul
    del /f /q "%TEMP%\_envget.tmp" 2>nul

    :: capture user / architecture
    SET "OriginalUserName=%USERNAME%"
    SET "OriginalArchitecture=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"

    :: Set these variables
    call "%TEMP%\_env.cmd"

    :: Cleanup
    del /f /q "%TEMP%\_env.cmd" 2>nul

    :: reset user / architecture
    SET "USERNAME=%OriginalUserName%"
    SET "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=%OriginalArchitecture%"

    echo | set /p dummy="Finished."
    echo .```
````

Answer (score -1):

Does a path need to set as 'System Variables'? If no, then you can set a path to User's PATH variable instead.

You will need to close command prompt then reopen again.

Type below.

```
echo %PATH%,
```

It should update with new.